# In what scenarios should I expect to explicitly need to implement a move constructor and move assignment operator?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, move-semantics

Given that a class actually **is moveable**, manually implementing the move constructor and move assignment operator for a class quickly become tedious.

I was wondering **when** doing so is actually a heavy, heavy, premature optimization?

For instance, if a class only has trivial POD data or members that themselves have move constructor and move assignment operator defined, then I'd guess that the compiler will either just optimize the shit out of the lot (in the case of PODs) and otherwise use the members' move constructor and move assignment operator.

But is that guaranteed? In what scenarios should I **expect** to explicitly need to implement a move constructor and move assignment operator?

**EDIT:** As mentioned below by Nicol Bolas in a comment to his answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9966105/6345, with Visual Studio 11 Beta (and before) **no** move constructor or move assignment operator **is ever** automatically generated. Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you find yourself implementing, any of:

- destructor
- copy constructor
- copy assignment

Then you should be asking yourself if you need to implement move construction.  If you "= default" any of the above, you should be asking yourself if you should then also "= default" the move members.

Even more importantly, you should be documenting and testing your assumptions, for example:

```
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<A>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<A>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<A>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<A>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<A>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<A>::value, "");
```

Comment: I know there has been a change lately about the generation of move constructor when the copy constructor was handmade (and equivalent for assignment). There was a discussion prior to that change about the effect of `= default`, if I remember correctly... may `= default` actually not end up generating the move constructor/assignment ?

Comment: @Matthieu : §12.8/11 describes the conditions in which a defaulted copy/move constructor for a class is defined as deleted.

Comment: @ildjarn: yes, however it changed recently I think. And I am not sure about what would led to deletion before and will not once the DR's resolution is implemented.

Comment: @Matthieu : Ah, I'm reading N3337; if rules have changed beyond that, I certainly don't have any knowledge of it. :-]

Comment: @MatthieuM.:  I believe you're referring to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1402 which is currently in ready status.  That means it is not official yet, but likely to be voted into a working draft this Fall.  This change will mean that move members do not get implicitly deleted as often as they do now.  I think this is a very good change.  But this change is also part of the motivation for my emphasis on the static_assert tests.  Between everyone learning a new spec, and the spec itself being a moving target, we live in difficulties times.  Test, test, test.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: this is the change I remembered yes, thanks for the reference. And I agree with your emphasis on tests. It's always a good idea, and even more so at the moment.

Answer (score 10):

First, move semantics only help for classes that hold resources of any kind. "Flat" classes don't benefit from it at all.

Next, you should build your classes out of "building blocks", like `vector`, `unique_ptr` and the likes, that all deal with the nitty-gritty low-level detail of resources. If your class is done as such, you won't have to write anything at all since the compiler will generate the members correctly for you.

If you need to write a destructor for, say, logging, generation of move ctors will be disabled, so you need a `T(T&&) = default;` for compilers that support it. Otherwise, this is one of the only places were to write such a special member yourself (well, except if you write such a "building block").

Note that the logging in the destructor and constructor can be done an easier way. Just inherit from a special class that logs on construction / destruction. Or make it a member variable. With that:

**tl;dr** Let the compiler generate the special member for you. This also counts for copy constructor and assignment operator, aswell as the destructor. Don't write those yourself.

(Okay, maybe the assignment operators, if you can identify them as a bottle neck and want to optimize them, or if you want special exception safety or somesuch. Though, the "building blocks" should already provide all that.)

Comment: Note that if you want even *basic* exception safety and have a member which might throw on copy assignment, you'll most likely *have* to implement copy assignment yourself, even if that member's class offers the strong exception guarantee. That is because the default implementation does member-wise assignment which might result in a partially assigned (and thus likely invalid) object if any but the last member throws on assignment.

Comment: Standard containers only help you with "simple" resources (essentially memory), though; for resources e.g. allocated on external devices you would need to write special allocators. It's often more practical to write your own "building block" class instead then.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Yes, but how many of those are you going to have? Maybe 4?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Through specifying a deleter, you can make `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` manage anything you want.

Answer (score 2):

Do it every time the default behavior is undesirable or every time the default ones have been deleted and you still need them.

The compiler default behavior for move is call the member and base move. For flat classes / buil-in types this is just like copy.

The problem is typically present with classes holding pointers or value representing resources (like handle, or particular indexes etc) where a move requires to copy the values in the new place, but also to set the old place to some "null state value" recognizable by the destructor. In all other cases, the default behavior is OK.

The problem may also arise when you define a copy (and the compiler deletes the default move) or a move (and the compiler deletes the default copy), and you need them both. In these cases, re-enabling the default may suffice.

Answer (score 2):

> In what scenarios should I expect to explicitly need to implement a move constructor and move assignment operator?

Under the following cases:

1. When you are using Visual Studio 10 or 11. They implement r-value references, but *not* compiler generated move semantics. So if you have a type that has members that need moving or even contains a moveable type (`std::unique_ptr`, etc), you *must* write the move yourself.
2. When you might need copy constructors/assignment operators and/or a destructor. If your class contains something that made you manually write copy logic or needs special cleanup in a destructor, odds are good that you'll need move logic too. Note that this includes *deleting* copy mechanisms (`Type(const Type &t) = delete;`). If you don't want to copy the object, then you probably need move logic or to delete the `move` functions too.

As others have said, you should try to keep the number of types that need explicit move or copy mechanisms to a bare minimum. Put these in utility "leaf" classes, and have most of your classes rely on the compiler-generated copy and move functions. Unless you're using VS, where you don't get those...

Note: a good trick with move or copy assignment operators is to take them by value:

```
Type &operator=(Type t) { std::swap(*this, t); return *this; }
```

If you do this, it will cover both move and copy assignment in one function. You still need separate move and copy *constructors*, but it does reduce the number of functions you have to write to 4.

The downside is that you're effectively copying twice if `Type` is made of only basic types (first copy into the parameter, second in `swap`). Of course, you have to implement/specialize `swap`, but that's not difficult.

Comment: So, in VS11, if I have a class with 3 `std::string` members, then the compiler will not automatically generate the move stuff that'll use `std::string`'s own move implementations?

Comment: @JohannGerell: You can remove the "if I have a class..." part from your statement. The correct formulation is, "The compiler will not automatically generate the move stuff" for **anything**. It doesn't matter if it contains moveable types or not; if you want a move constructor, you must implement it manually. Though in VS10's case, there was an excuse: the standard around that time also didn't have implicitly generated move constructors.

Comment: I believe you're correct, but I cannot find a written MS reference for that - you know one?

Comment: Found it: Stephan mentions it eloquently in the paragraph beginning with *[...] Rvalue references v3.0 adds new rules to automatically generate move constructors and move assignment operators under certain conditions...* at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I may have missed the point of your question. I'm taking your question to mean copy constructors.

Back in the 1990s when I learned C++, I was taught always to write a copy constructor when designing a class. Otherwise, and this may have changed with newer versions of the compiler, C++ will generate a copy constructor for you in the situations that require one.

That default copy constructor may not always work the way you want. This would especially be true if your class contains pointers, or you otherwise do not want the default byte-wise copy of a default copy constructor.

Finally, I was taught that by writing a copy constructor, you are taking exact control over how you want your class copied.

I hope this helps.

Comment: "move copy constructor" != "copy constructor".

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: My question is about move semantics, not copy semantics (which I have no questions at all about).

Comment: @fontanini: Actually a "move copy constructor" does not exist, only a copy constructor and (since C++11) a move constructor. Note that the question contains only the correct term "move constructor".

Comment: "This would especially be true if your class contains pointers" -- if your class contains owning raw pointers and is not a "building block" as pointed out in my answer, it's broken.

Comment: @celtschk: I **did** write "move copy constructor" first, but changed it 5 seconds after pressing "Done" - he might have read it during that time...

Comment: @celtschk if you check the question's edition history, you will see that it contained the term "move copy constructor" until the last edition.