# Does RTTI work with final?

Tags: c++, c++11, rtti

I am learning C++11 via C++11 FAQ from Stroustrup. I have a question.

If a virtual function is defined as final in a class, does RTTI (dynamic_cast and typeid) still work on its derived class?

---

@MSalters: My intention was, let say:

```
struct A {
    virtual void f() final; // only one virtual function, but final
};
struct B : A {
};
A* pa = new B;
B* pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa); // would this work? I guess it applies to typeid as well.
```

Comment: See my profile for a C++11 draft link. Complete finalised standard is not available freely, you have to pay for it, which is sad.

Comment: @RafałRawicki: On [GitHub](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/tree/master/papers) the newer N3376 (2012-02-28) is available.

Comment: @ipc: Also you can get n3376 directly from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf.

Comment: Ah, I believe this answers #2 http://stackoverflow.com/q/9965461/46642. I'm editing the question to keep only the first part.

Comment: @ipc I've read that N3242 differs from official only in editorial changes (typos etc.). Were there any meritorical changes since then?

Comment: what is the "final in a class"?

Comment: @VJovic (If (((a virtual function) ((is defined) (as final))) (in a class))) I hope Lispification helps :)

Comment: @RafałRawicki Yes, there were substantive changes between N3242 and N3290, although few. SFINAE was expanded to cover access control violations, and I think there were some other things. Fortunately, there has now been another draft *after* N3290 (i.e. for the next standard, but only typo/editorial changes), so you can again be up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a virtual function `final` in the base class prevents it from being overridden (10.3/4). It is still inherited, because all members are inherited (modulo chapter 12, special member functions). Therefore, the derived class is polymorphic (10.3/1) and RTTI works.

(I'm assuming you weren't going to make your dtor `final`. That doesn't work.)